# Android : using images on android app

Tags: android, android-listview

Various applications in **Android market uses various images**, eg. Logo Quiz apps have so many images(logos) . do they that involve some permissions?

is it better to have images stored in android app or have a web view corresponding to image and loading image from internet. (case when having large quantity of images in my app)

Comment: yes you can store in folder in drawable under res

Comment: means i can use any image from google images, download it and use it?

Comment: ya you can use any image

Comment: there are no legal issues involved? no extra permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store images inside the app easily inside the drawable folder. But try to use free-to-use images to avoid legal matters.I dont think using webview to view images is a good practice.Its better to store them inside the app.

Comment: what if i want images from google image search result .. 
does that require legal permissions?

Comment: Some of the images shown in search results have legal issues when using it commercially.So go to the web page and check whether its free to use or not.Some blogs provide such images which we can use commercially.But most of them have copyrights attached.So check before you use it.

Comment: most sites have no information regarding that. Most of the images are from various blogs. Is it good to be used ?

Comment: yeah that's true.Most of the sites say nothing about it.But we dont know about their terms of use.So its better to do some googling on free to use images and use them.At least you should mention the copyright owners or the place(blog or website) you found the images in your credits page.

Comment: but say i have more than 1k pics in use, it's not possible to do that. And what about various logo quiz kind applications? how they show images(logos)..

Comment: when it comes to commercial apps developed by comapanies, most of the time they create their own images.So try to get your images in legal way(create yourself or get a help from a graphic designer).But if your app is not commercial there is no issue like that.

Comment: [this page](http://www.iclipart.com/termsofuse.php) is an example of the terms of use published for their cliparts.